# How has the average TX fee on the Ethereum network changed over time?

Tags: gas, fees

TX fee meaning the gas price * gas limit of a transaction .

Average meaning, how much ETH (or WEI) are people spending on average on a transaction today (May 2017) vs 1 year ago (May 2016) vs the beginning (August 2015)

I would assume the fees themselves have gone up due to gas limit as people increase the gas necessary to interact with contracts, send tokens, etc.

However, there were some periods where the average gas price was much higher than it is now.

Mostly, I'm just curious.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2):

http://ethgasstation.info/index.php - Best site to get information on Gas prices. It also has a real-time calculator and near real-time recommendations for gas prices.

Comment: ethGasStation is excellent.

Answer (score 0):

Etherscan.io has an average [gas price chart](https://etherscan.io/chart/gasprice) as well as a [daily gas used chart](https://etherscan.io/chart/gasused). Aside from some blips (mostly during ICOs?), the average gas price has remained pretty constant lately. The [average number of transactions](https://etherscan.io/chart/tx) tracks gas usage pretty well, too (at least upon quick visual inspection). But if you take the ratio of transactions and gas, that might give you a proxy for how much the use of contracts is growing.